# asp.net core web api local https problems

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, https

I can not use HTTPS with my web api so I tried running this command:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

But I got this error :

> Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the certificate.
> There was an error trusting HTTPS developer certificate.

I also tried to clean and create a new one

```
dotnet dev-certs https -v
The HTTPS developer certificate was generated successfully.
```

But still facing the same issue.
I can not see localhost certificate in CurrentUser\Personal\Certificates

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3421

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this happens if you have multiple Certificates.

1. Execute certmgr.msc in Run
2. Clear all localhost certificates
3. On the commandline execute dotnet dev-certs https -t
4. You can check the certificate with dotnet dev-certs https --check. if this command returned nothing, every thing is OK.
5. run your application using dotnet run